# "Calling setState in render causes infinite loop" in react

Tags: reactjs

I want to set the state for subcategories but its showing Maximum update depth exceeded. How to overcome this? Please help and thank you.

```
getSubCategories(){
        let a = filter(this.state.allCategories,{'category_id': this.state.selectedCategoryId})
        let subCategories=[]
        a.map((c) =>{
            const value = {value: c.id, label: c.name}
            subCategories.push(value)
        })
        this.setState({subCategories:subCategories})
    }
```

The expected result is to set the state for sub categories.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! It would help if you can post a more detailed example. There's relevant code that's missing here. For example, it's likely you're calling `getSubCategories()` inside `render()`, but we can't know for sure.

Comment: Based on your code above, it's not clear what is causing the maximum update depth to occur. Could very likely be another piece of code that's calling getSubCategories repeatedly.

Comment: You don't want to call `setState` directly on render, so if you call `getSubCategories` in your render method it will cause an infinite loop.

Comment: calling setState triggers a render so calling a setState in your render function will loop. you are most likely calling `this.getSubCategories` in your `render()` so try putting it in a lifecycle function e.g. `componentDidMount()`

Answer (score 0):

`setState()` will trigger an update, which means that the component will `render` again. So you cant call setState in `render`, because it will keep updating and rendering all the time.

What you can do is that you can call `getSubCategories()` method on `componentDidMount()`, and it will work as expected.